# Movement in html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to figure out the right way to do movement in canvas. From my research it appears that a lot of tutorials use redrawing. I got movement to work by clearing my shapes and recreating them (redrawing?): http://pastebin.com/VuYdtM2U

I am wondering though if that is the way it is supposed to be done or if there is a better way. I can imagine clearing an image and creating it a pixel over every fraction of a second would get resource intensive.

Comment: Use svg instead of cavas and use translate to move whence you need not redraw any thing.

Comment: If you were to recreate maple story (i like that game), would you use svg or canvas?

Comment: Yes using `clearRect()` is the way to go.

Comment: I would prefer SVG if there are lot of movements of same objects else if every frame has entirely different entity coming in I would prefer canvas because svg is most useful when you have known entities and they may be moving around and also switches now and then. Look at [D3JS](http://d3js.org/) to know how well you can use SVG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, It is done this way only. Most of the Browser Games are coded this way and a lot of clearing and re rendering takes place seamlessly. Modern Browsers can handle a lot of rendering without any delay.

**The main reason behind this is that, Canvas is just a sort of image for the browser and it just draws on it and don't have to retain any Element DOM Structure.**

Whereas in case of SVG, all elements have to be appended / deleted /added to the DOM Structure which takes toll if there are a lot of elements.

There are several factors which can help us decide which technique is better as per the case.

Generally for Page with DOM elements less than 10,000...  Both are efficient.

You can also use mixture of Canvas , SVG and Multiple Canvas (like you may want to show a hover canvas, over another canvas)..

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```html
    
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" height=400 width=500>
<g>
<rect transform="translate(-20,-20)" height="40" width="40" style="fill:#777; stroke:none;"/>
<animateMotion fill="freeze" path="M 0 0 Q 190 160 150 70 T 200 150 T 300 200 T 200 200" dur="3.14159s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</g>
<path d="M 0 0 Q 190 160 150 70 T 200 150 T 300 200 T 200 200" style="fill:none;stroke:#F00;stroke-width:5"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Hum the question is about `<canvas>` and your answer uses `<svg>` ?

Comment: I do appreciate the answer, it is very useful, but I cannot accept it as the correct answer, as Kaiido pointed out, the question was about canvas. But this answer is actually exactly what I needed to hear.